# Is there any option to declare global variable in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, cordova

I am searching for a solution to declare global variable in sencha touch, but can't find. Is there any way? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in app.js like this

```
Ext.application({
 name: 'yourApp',
 globalVarible: ''
 ....
 ....
 ....
});
```